# Need Code Coverage for CRUD If Block, How can I achieve that?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, crud

```
  Here is my Controller Code --- 

    // creates a new Attachment__c record
 Attachment__c objAttach = new Attachment__c();
    private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {
        objAttach.Contact__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cid');
        objAttach.Account__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('aid');
        objAttach.Lead__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lid'); 
        objAttach.Case__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseid'); 
        objAttach.Product__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pid'); 
        objAttach.Opportunity__c=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('oid');         

        myParentID=(objAttach.Product__c!=null?objAttach.Product__c:(objAttach.Opportunity__c!=null?objAttach.Opportunity__c:(objAttach.Lead__c!=null?objAttach.Lead__c:(objAttach.Case__c!=null?objAttach.Case__c:(objAttach.Contact__c!=null?objAttach.Contact__c:(objAttach.Account__c!=null?objAttach.Account__c:null))))));

        if (!Schema.sObjectType.Attachment__c.isCreateable()){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'Insufficient access!'));
            return null;
        }
        return Database.insert(objAttach);
    }
```

Test Class :

Comment: can u share your current test class for this ?

Comment: I have inserted Attachment__c record only

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to have a Profile in your organization which don't have sufficient CRUD permission on custom object Attachment__c.

First you can create such profile then create a new user with that profile in test class and execute your controller code inside [System.runAs()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) method. And yes Profiles can be queried even with *(SeeAllData=false)*